# Scanf ignore some types of inputs

Tags: c, scanf

in my program i use the scanf function like this:

```
        if(((scanf("%c %d %d",&zp, &min, &max)) != 3) 
            || (zp != 'c' && zp != 'l')  || min < 0 || min > max){
            if (! feof (stdin)){
                printf("Wrong input.\n");
            }
            else{
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

so i expect, when i enter wrong input, and it's not EOF , the printf will be triggered. If i input two or three bad values,it works; but when input is only one value, it does nothing and waits for the second one...
for example, when i input:

```
l o b
```

it works; but when i input

```
a
```

it waits for second value.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Try adding space `"%c %d %d"` --> `" %c %d %d"`.  Report the numeric value of `zp` to see why.

Comment: that's the expected behaviour of scanf, it waits for your input o satisfy input condition

Comment: i found out, that the scanf does nothing with the first char, and check only the integers...